# How to make a jQuery http -> https AJAX request

Tags: javascript, jquery, apache, http-headers, cross-domain

I know this has been discussed many times so far, but I can't make it work :/ what am I doing wrong? Target page, when opened standalone, works correctly. Take a look at the screenshot:

[image]

Blurred IP is the same everywhere
Response is empty

Comment: it's just regular `jQuery.ajax({url: "https://xxx"});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are falling foul of the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

If you must cross domains (which going from HTTP -> HTTPS is counted as) you need to make a `JSONP` request.

Comment: which then means response needs to be json?

Comment: @Netismine that's correct. Unfortunately there is no other way.